# Rails Remember_token expected black? to return false, return true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, token

I'm at Hartl Ch. 8 Rails Tutorial and my test "remember token" failed.
Error message

```
User remember token
Failure/Error: it { @user.remember_token.should_not be_blank}
expected black? to return false, got true
```

Test Code

```
 describe "remember token" do
    before { @user.save }
    it { @user.remember_token.should_not be_blank }
    end
```

Model method

```
  def create_remember_token
    self.remember_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
    end
```

Any ideas why it doesn't work?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you paste all of the model code?

Comment: Where do you call your create_remember_token method? You could do this for example in a before_save hook. before_save :create_remember_token

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without knowing how you setup the rest of your model, or if this should only happen once or on each save, the design may change. It will depend on how you setup the hook which calls `create_remember_token`.

Assuming, you always want to ensure that a token exists, you can force if before your save:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :create_remember_token

  # Rest of code

  def create_remember_token
    # Only create this if it doesn't already exist
    self.remember_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64 unless remember_token
  end
end
```

For a more accurate tests, I would use:

```
describe User do

  subject(:user) { User.new } # Omitting required attributes

  context "on saving" do
    it do
      SecureRandom.stub(urlsafe_base64: "test_token")

      expect{user.save}.to change{user.remember_token}.from(nil).to("test_token")
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: Much thanks! Was my fault - i forgot about `before_save :create_remember_token`. Now it works!

Answer (score 0):

If you're following Hartl, I believe you actually want:

`class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :create_remember_token`

> To accomplish this, we’ll create an initial token using a callback, a technique introduced in Section 6.2.5 in the context of email uniqueness. In that section, we used a before_save callback; this time, we’ll use the closely related before_create callback to set the remember token when the user is first created